# How to update with method PUT django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

when prompted PUT (update) out this error

Can not call .is_valid () as no data = keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance.
my view:

```
    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
            queryset = Producer.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
            if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
                return ProducerSerializer(queryset,
                                          fields=('short_info',))

            if self.request.method == 'PUT' or self.request.method == 'PATCH':
                return ProducerUpdateSerializer

            else:
                return ProducerSerializer(queryset,
                                          fields=('website', 'phone', 'email', 'contacts', 'short_info'))

        def get_queryset(self):
            return Producer.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

my serializer

```
 class DynamicFieldsModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        # Instantiate the superclass normally
        super(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields is not None:
            for i in fields:
                print self.fields.pop(i)


class ProducerSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
    tags = TagListSerializerField()
    categories = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    contacts = ProducerContactSerializer(many=True)
    country = CountryField(country_dict=True)
    business_type = ChoicesSerializerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Producer
        fields = ('id', 'business_type', 'logo', 'name', 'slug', 'country', 'city',
                  'street_address', 'zip', 'short_info', 'info', 'website',
                  'categories', 'tags', 'contacts', 'email', 'phone')


class ProducerUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagListSerializerField()
    categories = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Producer
        fields = ('id', 'business_type', 'logo', 'name', 'slug', 'country', 'city',
                  'street_address', 'zip', 'short_info', 'info', 'website', 'categories', 'tags')
```

when prompted PUT (update) out this error

Can not call .is_valid () as no data = keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, I doubt your `get_serializer` is correct for PUT. It should return an instance while you return a class.

As for your issue, the error message is pretty clear. You are not passing the `data=request.data` to your serializer when instantiating it. Documentation contains [an example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#deserializing-objects) of how to do that.